# Notificaciones con FireBase Cloud Messaging y C sharp

Tags: android, c#, firebase

Tengo un problema ya desde ayer y quiero saber si es posible realmente el implementarlo.

Tengo una aplicación en C# desktop y otra en Android. Lo que me gustaría hacer es, en el caso se haga algo en la aplicación desktop (sea registro, update o eliminación), se notifique mediante FireBase a mi aplicación Android.

Lo que he podido hacer en mis pruebas es notificar a mi APP Android desde un evento de la consola de FireBase.

Mediante el siguiente código, con las credenciales de mi cuenta de FireBase he enviado una "notificación", sin recibir nada en mi APP Android, pero recibiendo una respuesta:

Código de notificación C#:

```
private static string SendPushNotification()
    {
        string response;

        try
        {
            // From: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/x.y.z/settings/general/android:x.y.z

            // Projekt-ID: x.y.z
            // Web-API-Key: A...Y (39 chars)
            // App-ID: 1:...:android:...

            // From https://console.firebase.google.com/project/x.y.z/settings/cloudmessaging/android:x,y,z
            // Server-Key: AAAA0...    ...._4

            string serverKey = "AAA......5"; // Something very long
            string senderId = "18......7";
            //string deviceId = "dj9...c:APA...    .....WTw"; // Also something very long, 
                                                            // got from android
            string deviceId = "/topics/android";             
                                                            // Use this to notify all devices, 
                                                            // but App must be subscribed to 
            // topic notification
            WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");

            tRequest.Method = "post";
            tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            var data = new
            {
                to = deviceId,
                notification = new
                {
                    body = "Greetings",
                    title = "Augsburg",
                    sound = "Enabled"
                }
            };

            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var json = serializer.Serialize(data);
            Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", serverKey));
            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", senderId));
            tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            using (Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                using (WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (Stream dataStreamResponse = tResponse.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStreamResponse))
                        {
                            String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
                            response = sResponseFromServer;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response = ex.Message;
        }

        return response;
    }
```

Respuesta

```
"{\"message_id\":82xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}"

"{\"multicast_id\":8580xxxxxxxxxx,\"success\":1,\"failure\":0,\"canonical_ids\":0,\"results\":[{\"message_id\":\"0:152xxxxxxxxx%0000000000000000\"}]}"
```

Por lo que he podido revisar la documentación, no hay algo oficial para C#. ¿Estoy en el camino correcto?, es posible hacer esto o tengo que hacer otra cosa.

Puntual, necesito notificar cambios en mi APP Android desde mi aplicación C#.

**Tengo:
 - Una aplicación WinForm hecha en Visual Studio C#
 - Una cuenta en FireBase CLoud Messaging
 - Una APP hecha en Android Studio.**

Gracias por cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Una pregunta, el dispositivo Android está suscrito a ese tema? Si no deberás enviarlo al token del dispositivo. Yo tengo algo parecido pero con asp-mvc, pero con el código similar al que has puesto

Comment: Hola, el destino que pongo es a todos los dispositivos Android, por lo que no estoy necesitando de un token (al menos por ahora), es decir, estoy enviando a todos la notificación. Cuando tu envias, que obtienes de respuesta?, es similar a lo que puse?

Comment: Yo además tengo puesta esta línea tRequest.ContentType = "application/json"; Para que le llegue a tu móvil Android, el móvil tiene que estar subscrito al tema Android de tu firebase: string deviceId = "/topics/android";  En algún sitio de tu app de Android has tenido que poner algo asi://        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("android");

Comment: Genial, en base a tu comentario sobre el token, he podido notificar como deseaba a un dispositivo en concreto. Voy a probar lo que mencionas sobre especificar ...("android") en la aplicación Android para poder enviar a todos los dispositivos android sin depender de un token rn específico.

Answer (score 0):

Si hay un [nugget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging/) para c# que es mantenido por Microsoft, es un wrapper de la librería oficial tanto para android como para iOS.

Es importante que en tu app le des los permisos para recibir notificaciones, habilites los métodos para manejarlas. En esta [guía](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=vswin) te explican paso a paso como configurar tu app para poder recibir.

Es importante que si vas a manejar notificaciones a dispositivos específicos debes obtener el token (que no es mas que un ID del teléfono) y ligarlo al usuario de tu app para poder enviar la notificación hacía ese token (es decir, hacía es usuario)

Comment: Esto funciona para una aplicación WinForm hecha en Visual Studio C#, una cuenta en FireBase CLoud Messaging, una APP hecha en Android Studio, me confirmas por favor

Comment: si, la comunicación entre tu app de android y Firebase Cloud Messaging es independiente de la fuente, puedes usar tu app de windows form, cualquier otro backend o hasta la consola de firebase